# My stack of Rigid Bodies jump up when I press play

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

How can I stop them from doing that so I can use another object to knock them over?

I tried following other suggestions, like change Shape, but I just don't get it.

It's a stack of cylinders that represent casino chips. They have a random translation that makes them being uneven, but that shouldn't be the culprit, right?

When I press play, they immediately jump up. I tried making sure they werent clipping the surface underneath, but no luck.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file?

Comment: this happens often if the rigid body do overlap....so you should check your collision margin, your positions and the sizes.

Comment: Might be worth it to space them out a bit and run the sim to settle them in place.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Looking at this again, seems like the table's collider is too high.